# on production Refresh causes code display

Tags: next.js, digital-ocean

On development, everything works fine, but when we push it to production on digitalocean at first everything is fine. However, when I refresh the pages, I get code like this as a result [image]

Does anybody have an idea what might be causing this? is it an error or the bundle code? not even sure. does any know what this might be and what might be causing it??

Comment: Update on my investigation. it is only happening on static pages. if the pages are generated dynamically it doesn't happen. and those pages get the 304 status code.